# My Application crashes if there is an unhandled exception in my Class Library?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

What I am doing is basicly creating a .DLL. I have a lots of stuff going inside these DLL-s, and it happens that I miss a scenario and something unexpected happens. I am working on it on unit tests, but I want to be hundred percent sure, that my WinForms app will never crash.

**What I have:**

One Solution with two projects:

- ProjectDLL (Class Library)
- ProjectWinForms (Windows Forms Application [.NET Framework])

**What I did:**

In ProjectWinForms I added this to `ApplicationEvents.vb`

```
  Private Sub MyApplication_UnhandledException(sender As Object, e As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs) Handles Me.UnhandledException
        Bugsplat_Lander.ExeptionToShow = e.Exception
        Bugsplat_Lander.Show()
        Bugsplat_Lander.BringToFront()
        e.ExitApplication = False
    End Sub
```

This works fine as long as the exception occurs in my ProjectWinForms project. However, if I build a Release version, move it to another computer, and create an exception; my application will simply close, and write the error in Windows Events.

**What I want to achive:**

Basicly the nicest thing would be to open up this form even if the exception happens in my ProjectDLL code, without quiting the application.

I am a sure that I am the one doing something wrong, I just can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first the golden rule is: If your code creates an exception, it has to be handled otherwise your application runs in a dirty state.
For your problem take a look to [Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.setunhandledexceptionmode?view=windowsdesktop-6.0). Maybe this could help you

Comment: Wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but using the Unhandled Exception Event I found on the link and some tweaking I achived what I wanted. Thanks!